# Is it possible to draw a 2-D plot on X11 display window using C?

Tags: c, linux, graphics, plot, x11

I was working on displaying some of the 2-D plots on X11 display. For example, values of X in X-axis and corresponding sin(X) in Y-axis, which should be displayed on the display window.

The only idea I have right now is to use two XDrawLines() for X-Axis and Y-Axis. Next step would be using XDrawPoints() for the corresponding points. However, I am doubtful about perfect visualization of these points over the two axes. Next issue would be how to interpolate the points so that a curve comes into picture, like sin(X).

Comment: Do you really want to work with Xlib? You can achieve way better results in more elegant code using Qt or another toolkit.

Comment: ...or not writing code at all. Have you played with GnuPlot?

Comment: Well, I am aware of GnuPlot and other plotting tools may be MATLAB etc. However, I was wondering whether it would be possible using Xlib, as some of the work related to this project has been done using Xlib.

Comment: It's obviously possible since Xlib lets you draw single pixels. Can you be more specific, for example "Are there functions in Xlib for drawing smooth curves and splines?" or "Is there a library that lets me draw smooth curves and splines Xlib surfaces?" or "Is there a simple graphing library that lets me render 2D plots on a Window created with Xlib?"

Comment: Well, unfortunately I am not aware of any such functions in Xlib for drawing smooth curves. As far as your question goes, yes I agree with the third one,"Is there a simple graphing library that lets me render 2D plots on a Window created with Xlib?". Simple saying, I wanted to write a C code using Xlib functions to draw a smooth curve.